# How to make sign-up form stationary on a sliding sign-in/sign-up when the sign-up button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm doing a side project where I'm creating a website with a sigin-in/sign-up form. I'm using HTML, CSS, PHP and some JavaScript to create the website. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.florin-pop.com/blog/2019/03/double-slider-sign-in-up-form/)  to create the following sliding sign-in and sign-up form. The GIF to demo it is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPUT0.gif)

When a user clicks on the sign-up button, the form slides so that the Create Account form appears.

What I want to achieve is that when the user fills in the create account page and clicks on the sign up button, there's PHP running at the back to do some user authentication and then displays a message in the window where "Welcome Back!" is orrignally meant to appear [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Rqj.png)

However, when the user clicks the sign-up button after filling out the form, the page seems to refreshes and is returned to the sign in form. It's only when I click on the sign up button on the sign in form that it goes back to the sign up form and displays the message on the back.

My question is how would I be able to make the sign up form stationary when the the sign up button is clicked so that the message can appear on the left.

Here is my code so far (loginRegister.html)....

```
<div class="container" id="contPadding">
<div class="cont" id="cont">
    <div class="form-container signup-container">
        <form method="POST">
            <h1>Create Account</h1>
            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>or use your email to join us</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name = "username"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name = "email"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name = "password"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name = "pwdConfirm"/>
            <input type = "text" placeholder="First Name" name = "firstName">
            <input type = "text" placeholder="Last Name" name = "lastName">
            <button id="Sign-Up">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="form-container signin-container">
        <form method="POST" action="authentication.php">
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
            <span>or use your account</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name = "username" required/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name = "password" required/>
            <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot your Password</a>
            <button type="submit" name="Sign-In">Sign In</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay-container">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                <?php
                require_once "db.php";
                if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['pwdConfirm']) && isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['lastName']) && isset($_POST['email']))
                {
                    // Declaring and Initializing variables from the registration form
                    $uname = $_POST['username'];
                    $pwd = $_POST['password'];
                    $pc = $_POST['pwdConfirm'];
                    $fname = $_POST['firstName'];
                    $lname = $_POST['lastName'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];

                    $usernameCheck = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName='$uname'";
                    $results = mysqli_query($db, $usernameCheck);
                    $table = mysqli_num_rows($results);

                    // Error checking the form to make sure it complies with the specifications given
                    if($uname == '' || $pwd == '' || $fname == '' || $pc == '' || $lname == '' || $email == '')
                    {
                        echo "<p class='error'>All fields must be filled in order to continue</p>";
                    }
                    else if($table > 0)
                    {
                        echo "<p class='error'>The user name that you have entered is already taken! Please enter a new username</p>";
                    }
                    else if($pwd != $pc)
                    {
                        echo "<p class='error'>The password that you have entered does not match! Please try again</p>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (userName, emailAddress, password, firstName, LastName) VALUES ('$uname', '$email', '$pwd', '$fname', '$lname')";
                        // Inserting the user's details into the database and displaying a confirmation message 
                        // to the user with a link to return to the login page
                        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                        echo '<p>Congratulations! Your account was created successfully. Click <a href="index.html">here</a> to return to the home page</p>';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo " <h1>Welcome Back!</h1> ";
                    echo " <p>To keep connected with us please log in with your account</p> ";
                    echo '  <button class="over-btn" id="signin">Sign In</button> ';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                <h1>Don't have an account?</h1>
                <p>Create an account by clicking the button bellow </p>
                <button class="over-btn" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

....and for the Javascript (loginRegister.js)

```
const signUpbtn = document.getElementById('signup');
const signInbtn = document.getElementById('signin');
const container = document.getElementById('cont');

signUpbtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   container.classList.add('right-panel-active')
});

signInbtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    container.classList.remove('right-panel-active')
});
```

...and finally the CSS (logReg.css)

```
#contPadding{
    padding: 25px;
}
h1
{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:0;
}

p{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}
span{
    font-size: 12px;
}
a{
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.cont
{
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow:  0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 546px;
    min-width: 50%;

}

.form-container
{
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    text-align: center;
}
.social-container
{
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.social-container a{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.form-container input{
    background:  #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.form-container button
{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

button
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaa23;
    background: #ffaa23;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;

}
button:active{
    transform: scale(0.95);
}
button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
button.over-btn
{
    background: transparent;
    border-color: #fff;
}
.social:hover
{
    color: #ffaa23;
    border-color: #ffaa23;
}
.form-container
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height:  100%;
    transition:  0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.signin-container
{
    left:0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index:2;
}

.signup-container
{
    left:0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index:1;
    opacity: 0;
}
.signup-container button
{
    background: #ff782b;
    border-color: #ff782b;
}
.signup-container .social:hover
{
    color: #ff782b;
    border-color: #ff782b;
}
.signin-container button
{
    background: #ffa705;
    border-color: #ffa705;
}
.signin-container .forgot
{
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


.overlay-container
{
    position: absolute;
    top=0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}
.overlay
{
    background: #ffaa23;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ed2a31,#ffaa23) no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay-panel
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 40px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition:  transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay-right
{
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.overlay-left
{
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}


.cont.right-panel-active .signin-container
{
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
.cont.right-panel-active .overlay-container
{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.cont.right-panel-active .signup-container
{
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
}


.cont.right-panel-active .overlay
{
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
.cont.right-panel-active .overlay-left
{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.cont.right-panel-active .overlay-right
{
    transform: translateX(20%);
}
```

I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me. I've been stuck on this for a while and would like to resolve it.

Cheers!

Comment: you can do it by having a container with `position:relative` and then 2 child with `transition` on their `left` and `right` property with `position:absolute` and `width:50%` , using onclick event changing their left and right . also 2 child inside the form container , one for login and one for signup , changing according to onclick

Comment: @BrightFaith Do you mind expanding on what you mean? I still want the forms to slide when clicking between the two, but I just want it stationary when the user fills out the sign in form and clicks the sign up button so that the message can appear on the left-hand side. Instead of the page refreshing and the user having to click on the sign up form to see the message

Comment: @BrightFaith I have what you said set up in the CSS and JavaScript. My problem is when I do the authentication in PHP and have it redirect to the page using header(Location:loginRegister.php), it brings me back to the sign in form. Rather, I want it to bring me to the sign up form without having to click on the sign up button

Comment: if that's your problem , you can easily solve it by sending a `GET` parameter in your redirect url , specifying which form must be shown , according to that parameter , you can put inline style inside them by php , or having separated css file including or not , to make which form be visible